# jumper.lua pathfinding library uncompatible with procedural generation?

Tags: lua, libraries, path-finding, procedural-generation

I discovered jumper.lua which is an incredibly fast and easy to use pathfinding library for grid-based maps.

However, it is giving me problems.

I am going to use this library with a procedurally generated map: as the player moves, a new 32 x 32 piece of terrain appears when needed.

This could make the map look non-rectangular of course. The problem is that when I try to create a Grid out of a non-rectangular map, the jumper.grid module warns ne with a `Bad argument #1. Not a valid map.` error.

Is there a way to bypass this while still making the library work?
Or should I search for another library?

Comment: You could store the unexplored space as wall until you explore it.

Comment: @DavisDude the map is theoretically infinite - I couldn't create an infinite wall map.

Comment: Also I've removed the `assert` causjng the error, now it works with my map, I just want to be sure it's still 100% safe to use it with non-rectangular maps.

Comment: Unless you're very familiar with the code in question, removing the `assert` is asking for trouble; its whole point to unsure that the program does proceed if a condition is met. Typically, it's used to make the program fail in an obvious way if an unexpected condition occurs. This suggests that jumper.lua was not designed to handle non-rectangular & processing them may invalidate assumptions made by the pathfinding code, thus you cannot assume the output is correct.